# Find unique elements in an array question in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, unique

I need to print all the unique elements in an array of ints but when I compile my program I get below error.

```
muratakar$ gcc Code.c 
    Code.c:20:39: error: expected expression
    int isUnique = uniqueElements(arr[], n);
```

Here is my code given below. Please help me to find the problem and fix it. Thanks in advance.

```
//Unique Elements Finder : Implement a C function to find all unique elements in an array.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int uniqueElements(int arr[], int n);
int main()
{
    system("clear");
    int arr[10];
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    int n;
   
    int isUnique = uniqueElements(arr[], n);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int uniqueElements(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n;++i)
    {
        int isUnique = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n;++j)
        {
            if(i!=j && arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                isUnique = 0;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        if (isUnique)
        {
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put `10` between [] but it did not help.

Comment: This `int isUnique = uniqueElements(arr[], n);` should be `int isUnique = uniqueElements(arr, n);`

Comment: What does your learning material (books, tutorials, teachers handouts, etc.) say about using an array and pass it around?

Comment: Another problem is that `n` has not been given a value.

Comment: Also note that the variable `n` will be *uninitialized*, and have an *indeterminate* value. Using it as the array size might cause your loops to go out of bounds, and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And *another* is that function `uniqueElements()` does not always return a value.

Comment: Break it down into the smallest possible problems. If you still can't solve that (and you almost certainly will be able to), post for help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Split task into smaller problems.

Here you have an example of the "brut force" implementation:

```
int isUnique(const int *array, const int val, const size_t size)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        //if found more than once the it is not unique
        if((count += (array[index] == val)) > 1) break;
    }
    return count == 1;
}

void printAllUnique(const int *array, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
        if(isUnique(array, array[index], size))
            printf("Unique value %d at pos %zu\n", array[index], index);
}
```

The compilation error: You need to use name of the array only:

```
int isUnique = uniqueElements(arr, n);
```

Comment: 1) This does not address OP's trouble with `int n;  int isUnique = uniqueElements(arr[], n);` 2) Both OPs' approach and this code are `O(n*n)`.  `O(n*log(n))` solution begins with a sort.  3) This answer could do half the iterations with `if(isUnique(array +index, array[index], size - index)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I wanted to show that splitting the task into smaller problems can significantly improve the readability and program logic. It was not my intention to write an efficient (I even wrote - brut force) solution for the given problem.

Comment: Good that code demos splitting the task into smaller problems, yet it does not address the post's lead issue of "my program I get below error." --> "error: expected expression"

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your code involving variables not being initialized before use and not all paths in your `UniqueElements` function having return values. Both leave you with [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Your basic approach, though, is brute force. For each element, check if it occurs again in the array. This is easily implemented, but it has O(n<sup>2</sup>) runtime complexity, which is not ideal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t unique_elements(int *arr, size_t n int *dest) {
    size_t final_size = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int unique = 1;
 
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i == j) continue;

            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                unique = 0;
                break;
            }
        }  

        if (unique) {
            dest[final_size++] = arr[i]
        }
    }

    return final_size;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[10] = {1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 6, 1};
    int unq[10];

    size_t s = unique_elements(arr, 10, unq);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) 
        printf("%d\n", unq[i]);
}
```

This will print:

```
2
8
7
```

A better way to approach this is to first sort the array, which can generally be done in O(n * log n) runtime complexity, and then add any elements that do not match either of their neighbours to the `dest` array.

The loop after the sort is now O(n).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int intcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int c = *(int *)a;
    int d = *(int *)b;

    return c - d;
}

size_t unique_elems(int *arr, size_t n, int *dest) {
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(int), intcmp);
    
    size_t final_size = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((i == 0 && arr[i] == arr[i+1]) ||
            (i == n - 1 && arr[i] == arr[i-1]) || 
            (i > 0 && i < n - 1 && 
             (arr[i] == arr[i+1] || arr[i] == arr[i-1]))) {
            continue;
        }

        dest[final_size++] = arr[i];
    }

    return final_size;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[10] = {1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 4, 7, 6, 1};
    int unq[10];

    size_t s = unique_elems(arr, 10, unq);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) 
        printf("%d\n", unq[i]);
}
```

Result:

```
2 
7 
8
```